# Filling jagged array with dynamic textboxes

Tags: c#

I made a Linear equation solver program for school, I already found an algorithm which works, but it uses jagged arrays.

I need your help to make dynamical textboxes which are filling up a jagged array. For example: `1x+1y=3` and `2x+1y=4` would go into a `{1,1,3}` and into a `{2,1,4}` array. Here is my code, which isn't working.

```
TextBox[][] tb = new TextBox[n][];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j < n+1; j++) {
      tb[i][j] = new TextBox();
      tb[i][j].BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
      tb[i][j].Left = 36 * j + 10;
      tb[i][j].Top = 36 * i + 10;
      tb[i][j].Width = 35;
      tb[i][j].Font = new Font(tb[i][j].Font.FontFamily, 16);
      tb[i][j].BackColor = Color.Cyan;
      tb[i][j].TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Dummy project preview]

---

I created a dummy project (as shown in the picture) and added a Panel. The Panel will contain the textboxes that you generate dynamically. I also updated the code behind. Although you created the textboxes, you never added it to any of the existing controls. They merely existed.
The code behind now looks like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int numVars = 2;

    // You'll eventually need to obtain the values in the boxes
    TextBox[][] tb;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Remove existing controls
        this.panel1.Controls.Clear();

        // Obtain number of variables
        numVars = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;

        // Create the TextBoxes
        tb = new TextBox[numVars][];

        // Initialize each jagged array
        for(int i = 0; i < numVars; i++)
            tb[i] = new TextBox[numVars + 1];

        // Create the Textboxes
        int height = 20;
        int width = 50;
        int curX = 10;
        int curY = 10;
        for(int i = 0; i < numVars; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < numVars + 1; j++)
            {
                TextBox txtbox = new TextBox();
                txtbox = new TextBox();
                txtbox.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                txtbox.Left = curX;
                txtbox.Top = curY;
                txtbox.Width = width;
                txtbox.Height = height;
                txtbox.Font = new Font(txtbox.Font.FontFamily, 16);
                txtbox.BackColor = Color.Cyan;
                txtbox.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;

                tb[i][j] = txtbox;
                this.panel1.Controls.Add(tb[i][j]); // Add as a child of panel

                curX += width + 15;
            }

            curX = 10;
            curY = curY + height + 20;
        }
    }
}
```

Running it with a value of 6 gave:[image]

Comment: Hi! @Frank
I tried to copy the textbox content into a real jagged array but an error message appeared while debugging, which says:"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."Do you know what could be the problem?thanks!         for (int a = 0; a < numVar; a++)
             {
                 for (int b = 0; b < numVar+ 1; b++)
                 {
                     variables[a][b] =int.Parse(TB[a][b].Text);

                 }
             }

Comment: Did you initialize each jagged array? (just like we initialized the TextBox jagged arays)